# Turtlebot Kinect fails since dropped 100.00% of messages and wireless crashed

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, wireless, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am planning to test "Visualizing TurtleBot Kinect Data". I followed the tutorial from this:  http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data

I started the turtlebot service on the Laptop, use "lsusb" , I saw the device id of Kinect, so I am sure that the Kinect is recognised correctly by the operating system.

### Here is the output from the Turtlebot Laptop.

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch

```
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f79eacf2-5bd6-11e1-9247-485d607d9b81/roslaunch-turtlebot-laptop-2850.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.101:38535/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_camera/image_mode
 * /openni_camera/image_time_offset
 * /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/depth_mode
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_camera/depth_registration
 * /openni_camera/debayering
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /openni_camera/shift_offset
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [2877]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [2878]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [2882]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [2883]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [2884]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [2885]
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f79eacf2-5bd6-11e1-9247-485d607d9b81/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1329751680.368102392]: [/openni_camera] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1329751680.368697517]: [/openni_camera] 1. device on bus 001:09 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00363914970053A'
[ WARN] [1329751680.372477514]: [/openni_camera] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1329751680.445963003]: [/openni_camera] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:9 with serial number 'A00363914970053A'
[ INFO] [1329751680.503487021]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1329751680.510222876]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'
```

### Here is my Rviz output from the console when I run Rviz on my workstation.

```
rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1329925027.700765660]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1329925027.700862731]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1329925027.700885502]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1329925027.827477567]: Loading general config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1329925027.827697158]: Loading display config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1329925027.841158666]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1329925028.176180815]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1329925028.194146525]: Texture for pass 1: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1329925028.287014274]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ WARN] [1329925031.734023957]: Message from [/openni_manager] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [camera_rgb_optical_frame]. Resolved locally to [/camera_rgb_optical_frame].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1329925032.081466459]: Message from [/openni_manager] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [camera_rgb_optical_frame]. Resolved locally to [/camera_rgb_optical_frame].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1329925040.037531448]: Message from [/openni_manager] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [camera_rgb_optical_frame]. Resolved locally to [/camera_rgb_optical_frame].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1329925043.463173666]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1329925049.720714694]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ INFO] [1329925086.578157405]: Saving general config to [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1329925086.578714220]: Saving display config to [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/display_config]
Killed
```

I am using Ubuntu10.04 x64 on the TurtleBot Laptop, installing ROS Electical version. On my workstation, the OS is Ubuntu10.04, installing ROS Electrical.

But every time, when I add camera from Rviz, the wireless connection between the TurtleBot Laptop between the Router would be crashed. This was very strange. How can a software make the wireless connection fail?

Do you have any advices or do you have the same problem?

Thanks in advance. Shan.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29298/turtlebot-kinect-fails-since-dropped-100.00%-of-messages-and-wireless-crashed/) by [Shan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1928/shan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-04**:
I have exactly the same setup (Ubuntu 10.04, ROS electric...) and exactly the same problem (dropped 100% of messages). So what is the solution ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
One straight issue i see here is with the capacity of the transfer of clouds and images over the wireless communication. Advice would be to process the cloud and images at the laptop itself and get the results to the router. It might be actually problem with the configuration of the laptop.

Thanks, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-04**:
Would you explain in more detail what commands we need to type? Thank you very much.